# Permission restriction on editing column in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint

We have one list in sharepoint in which users can add their record.
There is one column which should default to a value,but should not be visible to the user.
Admins should be able to see it and edit it.

I edited the original view to hide that column. But on edinting the hidden column is still available for editing.
Created a new view with different URL for admins with that column as well.

Is the approach correct?
How can I default value of the column when user adds a record.

How can I different permissions for different view?

Answer (score 0):

From [this article](http://sharepointpromag.com/blog/3-approaches-restricting-access-sharepoint-columns-and-metadata):

> Once a user has access to an item or document, it is not possible to
>   restrict their access at a column level. The permission the user has
>   to the item (view, edit, delete, create) is the permission the user
>   has to all columns in the item.
>
> Microsoft product group members have said, repeatedly and in all kinds
>   of forums, that column-level security is not supported and, when asked
>   about future versions of SharePoint, have said (in effect) “over our
>   dead bodies.”
>
> The issue seems to be performance. Column-level security would put
>   such a burden on every activity that SharePoint and (more
>   specifically) SQL would not be able to scale in the near-infinite
>   manner that Microsoft requires in order to support a feature.

The article also elaborates on approaches you can use to secure SharePoint at the column level but warns that:

> Make sure that you test any approaches against your workloads and
>   content, to be sure that the impact on performance is understood and
>   acceptable.

There's a project on CodePlex - [SharePoint Column & View Permission](https://spcolumnpermission.codeplex.com/) - which also might be able to help you out.